# Please explain some example code with squart

Tags: c, compare

Can someone explain what the following code does? I'm new to programming, I'm currently learning C.

`const void * a`

`return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );`

`qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);`

```
/* qsort example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* qsort */

int values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25 };

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
 return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main ()
{
  int n;
  qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
  for (n=0; n<6; n++)
     printf ("%d ",values[n]);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

This gives : 10,20,25,40,90,100

Comment: `qsort` sorts `values`, an array of length `6 int`, using the `compare` function to perform comparison. Your code comes from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
const void * a
```

Means that parameter passed to a function is a **pointer to void type**  and its value is **read only**.

This line:

```
( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
```

dereferences passed pointer interpreting them as pointers to `int` and calculates difference between these values.

And this:

```
qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
```

Is a call of the `qsort()` function of the standard library, where `compare` is a fucntion that actually compares values.